# How pass objects from AppDelegate to WindowController using Storyboards?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstoryboard

In my application delegate I create a `NSManagedObjectContext` property that I want to pass to the window controller I launch in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

This is basically my code in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSStoryboard *storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    self.setupWindowController = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"setup"];
    self.setupWindowController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    [self.setupWindowController showWindow:self];
}
```

In `MyWindowController.m` I have the following method:

```
- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    ((MyViewController *)self.contentViewController).managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
}
```

And this is a method from `MyViewController.m`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(NSStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.destinationController isKindOfClass:self.class]) {
        ((MyViewController *)segue.destinationController).managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

This approach worked pretty well until I had to programmatically launch different windows from the application delegate. 
The problem now is that `prepareForSegue:sender:` for the initial view is called before I'm able to set the `MyWindowController.managedObjectContext`, so it'll only pass `nil` with the following segues.

How on earth should I pass objects from my app delegate to the initial window controller before it sets up the view hierarchy?

Am I approaching all this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reducing the dependencies among controllers by making a data model layer in your application.

The data model would manage the information that the controllers use and provide an application-specific facade in front of CoreData.  The data model object(s) can be shared instances or can be requested from a known object, such as the app delegate.

That way, the model is only referenced where needed and doesn't clutter interfaces just as a pass-through object.

Comment: Apple recommend that you pass your `NSManagedObjectContext` instance to your view controllers and the docs actually says that you typically shouldn't retrieve the context from a global object, such as the application delegate. So there must be a better solution than this.

Comment: Where do they recommend that?  (I know they do it in the example "starter" apps  but it scales very poorly.)  However, I'm not actually recommending that your controllers get the context, rather that only the data model knows about the details of saving and that the controllers talk to it in terms of application data functions.  Then, if you ever substitute something else for CoreData, there's a limited amount of change involved rather than every controller.

Comment: When revisiting [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW2) I see that it only applies to iOS applications, for OS X it seems like you're actually supposed to retrieve the context from the application delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!  (I'm still not convinced that controllers should know how objects are persisted and retrieved at all, so I'll continue promoting the idea that the "M" part of MVC matters.  :) )